# How to set "use-commit-times" config option at repository level in SVN to retain modification timestamp on files

Tags: svn

Whether "use-commit-times" needs to be set to yes on every client m/c config file OR is there any option to centralize this on Subversion installation directory?.

Answer (score 2):

There is no mechanism in Subversion to do this.  use-commit-times is a client-side setting, not a server configuration.

What kind of computer/network do you have?  Is it Windows + Active Directory?  If so, you can use [Group Policy Preferences](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24449) to push a standard SVN configuration out to every workstation.  In the case of Windows, SVN client configuration can be done as either a file, or in the Registry.

If this is Unix/Linux environment, you can use a script to push a standard SVN config file out.

Keep in mind there is both a system-wide SVN config file, and a per-user SVN config file.  Not sure which one would be a better fit for your setup.  ([info about the config file](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.confarea.html))

In our environment, we use Group Policy to deploy a standard SVN config file to all the engineering workstations with some common items like default global-ignores.